# Magento 2: Add new function to an extension

Tags: magento2

I have installed an extension and need to add a new function to it without editing the core extension files.

I need to add a function in this file/class:
**Vendor/vendor_name/module_name/block/Post/View.php**

How is this done?

Comment: You can directly open the file and add your function, assume the need is in the template file, in the .phtml file you can use $block->myfunction();

Comment: Ok, yes my intention was to use the function in a template file. But I don't want to edit the extension "core" file so it could be overwritten on updates. I thought there was a way doing this within my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish what you're after is to create a new module and then use the new modules's di.xml to set a preference for the file you want to add the function to, extend it, and then add your new function.

So say you've got Vendor/Module1 that you have View.php in and you want to add a function to it.  Create Vendor/Module2 and then in Module2's etc/di.xml put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="VENDOR\MODULE1\Block\Post\View"
                type="VENDOR\MODULE2\Block\Post\View" />
</config>
```

Then create your new Module 2 View.php and have it extend Module 1's View.php like

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\MODULE2\Block\Post;

class View extends \VENDOR\MODULE1\Block\Post\View
{
    public function myAdditionalFunction()
    {
        echo "Hello world";
    }
}
```

Now you can update Module1 and not have to worry about your additional function getting overwritten in the update.